# How to run the cases parallelly with different browser(Chrome) languages in selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario to run the cases parallelly with different browser languages (Like English and French) with selenium Webdriver, is there any way to achieve the above scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel execution can be achieved using TestNG in selenium. You can parameterize the language in which you would like to launch the test and then using testNG you can run parallel tests with different language parameters.

Comment: Thank you Vishalgada for your quick response, can this be achieved using Scala Test framework?

Comment: @krishnapradeep I do not have an idea on Scala Test framework. But on searching the issue I found this link. May be this can help.
https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/1.4.1/org/scalatest/ParallelTestExecution.html